# antlr4: how to generate listener callback for token without a production rule?

Tags: antlr4

After I investigated the grammar quoted in the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751423/antlr4-grammar-ambiguity-left-recursion-both), it is clear the crux of the problem is centered on these production rules:

```
TIMESPAN  : startTime (WS THRU WS endTime)? ;
startTime : TOD ;
endTime   : TOD ;
```

The reason for the intermediate production rules `startTime` and `endTime` is to generate listener callbacks for those so I don't have to explicitly parse them in the TIMESPAN listener.  But evidently, that confuses the `antlr4` parser.  To fix the issue, I simplified the rules as follows:

```
TIMESPAN  : TOD (WS THRU WS TOD)? ;
```

and went further with this change:

```
TIMESPAN  : (TOD THRU TOD) | TOD ;
```

Either of those rules makes the grammar compile.

Since antlr4 no longer supports labels like this:

```
TIMESPAN  : (startTime=TOD THRU endTime=TOD) | startTime=TOD ;
```

my question is how can I tokenize the input to this grammar so as to capture `startTime` and `endTime`?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like antlr4 by convention generates listeners for non-capitalized rules (Eg, startTime and endTime), but not for capitalized ones (Eg, TIMESPAN).  I suppose the latter are understood to comprise "basic" components of a token (Eg, digits or string sequences) for which listeners need not be generated.  I'm not the antlr4 expert, so I will wait for comments... if someone wants to post a formal response, I'll give you credit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer here is that in antlr:

- Production rules for which the left-hand side is capitalized comprise lexer-related rules -- that is, you actually get tokens that your logic can then deal with accordingly.
- Production rules for which the left-hand side is not capitalized comprise parser-related rules -- that is, rules that further decompose the left-hand side into either expressions (ie, additional production rules), tokens, or both.

The listener in antlr4 is a suitable place where you can intercept results for appropriate parser rules.  In this example, you would set up a listener that sets `startTime` and `endTime` in a listener callback -- and then when the tree-traversal is done, use those values as needs be.

Comment: In a combined grammar file, rules beginning with capital letter are lexer rules, and rules beginning with non-capital are parser rules. Lexer rules are handled by Antlr, parser rules are to be handled by user's code.

Comment: Thank you.  I've edited my response to fall in line with your comment.  Thanks for the correction.